# Magento Error Messages are showing up twice

Tags: php, magento, duplicates, message

I seem to have an issue with our cart and I am unsure if it's theme related or not! All error/normal messages (local or global) are showing up TWICE on the front end. Not sure what is causing this issue. It doesn't mater if I'm adding to a cart, editing a cart, deleting an item from a cart, changing the address - all messages are showing up twice.

I looked through my error logs and nothing shows up.

Has anyone else had this issue with Magento? I'm using 1.7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be an issue with your theme. Magento has a block called global_messages, maybe your theme renders this block twice, although those are flash messages. If you say you see those messages only in cart you should look in your theme layout folder in the file checkout.xml, look for any of these lines:

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" />
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" />
```

Try deleting one or both if you find them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case previous developer has written following way in the page.xml file

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
   <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>   <!-- This was the area or problem as it is subblock in the core/text_list block it was getting rendered twice -->
    <label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
```

It should be like following way

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

 <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">               
       <label>Main Content Area</label>
 </block>
```